Disabling specific years in datepicker
I'd like to disable some specific years in https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/. With "disable" I mean they should not appear in the year drop-down (I'm using changeYear: true) and ideally they should be skipped when using the next/prev buttons.
I can disable specific dates so they are not selectable, and I can restrict the year range. But the disabled dates are still displayed, and when all dates in a year somewhere in the middle of the range are going to be disabled, I'd rather skip that year completely.
I manage to hide a year (at least in Firefox) with this CSS:
.ui-datepicker-year option[value='2023'] {
  display: none;
}

but when I try something similar programmatically, it has no effect:
$( function() {
  $('.ui-datepicker-year option').each( function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '2022') {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
      console.log('should hide ',$(this).val());
    }
  });
});

Full example:


$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: '2020-01-01',
    maxDate: '2025-12-31',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  });

  $('.ui-datepicker-year option').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == '2022') {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
      console.log('should hide', $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
.ui-datepicker-year option[value='2023'] {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
  Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
</div>



which must have something wrong, because there's nothing on the console, although a similar code in a more complex page does show should hide 2022. So, any ideas?

It seems the date picker options are not created at time the code runs, therefore this ('.ui-datepicker-year option').each(function() has no effect because the options list is empty.
I am not familiar with jQuery date picker, but a workaround is to add CSS rules for each year to the document:
const disabled_years = [2021, 2023, 2024];
var style = document.createElement('style')
disabled_years.forEach(function (year) {
    style.innerHTML += `.ui-datepicker-year option[value='${year}'] {display:none}`;
});
document.body.appendChild(style);




$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: '2020-01-01',
    maxDate: '2025-12-31',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  });
});

const disabled_years = [2021, 2023, 2024];
var style = document.createElement('style')
disabled_years.forEach(function(year) {
  style.innerHTML += `.ui-datepicker-year option[value='${year}'] {display:none}`;
})
document.body.appendChild(style);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
  Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
</div>



